# Подскажите как позиционировать данный header

Tags: html, flexbox, float, позиционирование, grid

[image: header]

Сижу не могу понять. Мне нужно просто знать через какое позиционирование и именно как. Детали конечно не нужны.

Comment: absolut будет достаточно

Comment: к каждому элементу?)

Comment: зачем к каждому элементу ? обернуть всё что должно быть в центре в блок и его отправить абсолютом в центр

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разумеется что этот пример просто обучающий и не адаптивный и потому смотреть этот пример надо на полный экран

Скачать эту вёрстку можете из [песочницы](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/rgVVNR) где я собственно и делал это

На github превью на полную страницу: https://anonimuslensky.github.io/index.html

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrOnw.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.item:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.menu {
  background: #131313;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.item1 {
  width: 40%;
}

.item1 .svg {
  display: block;
  width: 152px;
  margin: auto;
}

.item2 {
  display: flex;
}

.menu a {
  display: block;
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu a:hover {
  color: #fbfbfb;
}

.menu a:hover:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -14px;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid #ea2935;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ea2935;
  padding: 11px 0;
}

.item-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 100;
}

p:nth-of-type(1) span {
  font-size: 24px;
}

p:nth-of-type(1) span:nth-of-type(1) {
  color: #fff;
}

p:nth-of-type(1) span:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: #ea2935;
}

p:nth-of-type(2) {
  padding: 40px 0;
  color: #fbfbfb;
}

.item-inner a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.item-inner a:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: #ea2935;
  color: #fbfbfb;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 12px 20px;
}

.item-inner a:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: #222;
  color: #fbfbfb;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 12px 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="menu">
  <div class="item1">
    <div class="svg">
      <svg viewbox="0 0 150 100">
      <path d="M0,0 148,0 148,50 130,100 20,100 0,50z"  fill="#0C0E14" stroke=" #ea2935" stroke-width="2px"/>
      <text x="30px" y="80px" fill="#fff" stroke="none" style="font-size:22px;font-family:sans-serif;">Creativia</text>
    </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item2">
    <a href="#">home</a>
    <a href="#">about</a>
    <a href="#">portfolio</a>
    <a href="#">clients</a>
    <a href="#">team</a>
    <a href="#">services</a>
    <a href="#">blog</a>
    <a href="#">contacts</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-inner">
    <p>
      <span>lorem</span>
      <span>ipsum</span>
    </p>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis asperiores reiciendis architecto veniam aliquid velit sed cumque necessitatibus quas iste! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam, culpa!</p>
    <p>
      <a href="#">features</a>
      <a href="#">free psd</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо

Comment: @МаксимГорщевский отметить решением и поставить палец вверх можно ?

Comment: уже сделал. но я новичок, из-за этого палец вверх не видно визуально

Comment: Вы одним дивом захватили центральный текст. Я ломал голову и делал как два отдельных элемента, морочился с гридами и тд, но не мог никак. Теперь я даже понял как через гриды сделать, ибо просто надо было их в одну секцию, а дальше центрирование по середине и готово.